# Checking the users is for meeting the requirement on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm making an web with point and reward system where user collect points and if users point meet the requirement, user will get a reward and level up.

As example, here's my user table

```
id | username | level | point
1  | nameuser | 0     | 0
```

Award :

```
idaward | awardname | pointreq | badgeid
1       | LEVEL ONE | 10       | 1
```

and so on, I have 100+ award for user.

Award log

```
idlog | userid | awardid | badgeid | givendate
```

And my purpose is how to check if user is eligible or meet the requirement to get an award & badge ?

The flow:

```
Users have a point -> check if user meets the requirement to level up & get award 
-> Users will leveled up and get a reward (insert the info. to award log)
    If users already have it then ignore it.
```

I'm using Laravel, so if you can make the Laravel query, I will really appreciate it but I will also accept raw MySQL query.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute the following update query:

```
UPDATE user
SET level = level + 1
WHERE
id = ?
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM award WHERE pointreq <= user.point 
    AND awardid NOT IN (
        SELECT awardid from awardlog WHERE userid = user.id
    )
);
```

If the update returns 1 then you need to insert an entry into awardlog table, you can use following `SELECT` and `INSERT` queries for it:

```
SELECT * FROM award WHERE pointreq <= user.point 
AND awardid NOT IN (
   SELECT awardid from awardlog WHERE userid = user.id
);
```

You can get awardid and badgeid from above query and insert into awardlog.

Also, you need to make sure all 3 queries (`UPDATE`, `SELECT` and `INSERT`) get executed in a single transaction for consistency.